# what does "in that" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This experiment was critical in that the researchers synthesized ideas
>   proposed by prior studies that had suggested evidence for a strength
>   model of willpower.

Quote from "Early experimental evidence" in [Ego_depletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_depletion) of Wikipedia.

I feel quite confused about the meaning of this sentence. I hope to get some detailed explanations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A clumsy restatement would be

> This experiment was critical, and *the reason it was critical was* that the researchers synthesized ideas ...

"In that" introduces an explanation for the previous word or phrase, particularly if the word or phrase was true only in a narrow sense.

> The verdict was irrelevant, in that the defendant had died.  It was, however, a vindication for the victim.

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+that), **in that** is an idiom and it means *for the reason that, because*. Consequently, your sentence can be understood as:

> This experiment was critical *because [for the reason that]* the researchers synthesized ideas proposed by prior studies that had suggested evidence for a strength model of willpower.

Answer (score 0):

"in that", "that" means "This experiment". I think it's called

> that subordinate clause